# Opengl lwjgl: cant get camera move forward

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

With below instructions, I can strafe camera left-right, up-down and can rotate pitch+yaw using mouse and keyboard but I couldnt move forward or backwards:

Starting of drawing:

```
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();

GL11.glTranslatef((-(float)horizontalstrafe)*0.15f, (-(float)verticalstrafe)*0.15f, 0);
GL11.glTranslatef(0, 0, ((float)-forward)*0.15f);// does not move!

GL11.glRotatef((float)mouseAngleY, -0.02f, 0, 0);
GL11.glRotatef((float)mouseAngleX, 0, 0.02f, 0);
```

Why doesnt it move? When I press the necessary button, it just disappears after sometime and get visible again if I press opposite button for enough time.

Init part:

```
 GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MATRIX_MODE);
 GL11.glLoadIdentity();
 GL11.glOrtho(-2.0 * aspect, 2.0 * aspect, -2.0, 2.0, 0.1f, 3.0f);
```

Note: the object I need to see has vertices between the boundaries of x:[-1,1], y:[-1,1], z:[-1,1]

Comment: How would you know if you move forward in an Orthographic projection other than things disappearing out of the frustum? Try perspective projection and you'll see that everything is fine as it is.

Comment: You are right. It doesnt have a depthness feeling. How can I change to perspective?

Comment: If you want 3D then don't use Orthographic projection, you need to use Perspective Projection.

Comment: GLU.gluPerspective(fov, aspect_ratio, near, far); <- that should do the trick!

Comment: Thank you very much. Ill look for GLU packages, they seem to be having helper methods.

Comment: It's not directly related to your problem but you are somehow mixing up your matrices. For the actual projection part you should use the projection matrix. And for rendering i would use the modelview matrix and not the projection matrix as you do! And GL_MATRIX_MODE is no matrix that can be used.

Comment: @SIGSKILL okay I wrote a camera class that uses proper matrices thank you.